# Не работает буфер обмена когда открыт скрипт

Tags: python, clipboard

Делаю программу на Python, и когда она работает перестает работать буфер обмена (ничего нельзя скопировать). Почему? И как это можно решить?

Comment: чёто шар для гадания совсем мутный. значит у вас проблема в программе на 65й строчке нужно изменить

Comment: @Интик простой код на tkinter, я не взаимодействовал в коде с буфером обмена никак, просто ничего нельзя скопировать, вам скинуть чтоли код на 800 строк?

Comment: скиньте. ведь если проблему нельзя воспроизвести, то её не существует. это вам любой тестер скажет. ну и в целом нехватает подробностей начиная с ОС

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй через диспетчер задач выключить питон, при работе с некоторыми библиотеками он там зависает. У меня так было, когда случайно запустил скрипт с pytorch без виртуальной среды.